# Element type is invalid on routes react-router-redux

Tags: reactjs, routes, router, react-router-redux

I got the following error when I try to add routes on my app and I dont know what Im doing wrong, I tried to follow the doc guide

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `AppRoutes`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import SignUp from '../../screens/SignUp';

import { history } from '../../../redux/store';

function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} />
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed react-router-redux like this:

```
npm install --save react-router-redux
```

or

```
yarn add react-router-redux
```

This installs the 4.x version and because of that you are getting this error. If you look the documentation carefully you will see the instruction as:

```
npm install --save react-router-redux@next
```

or

```
yarn add react-router-redux@next
```

After installing the "next" version which is 5.x, this error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install steps in a correct order. You can take a look at the following link: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5428.
teps to reproduce

Create a new app
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app react-router-params
cd react-router-params/

Install react router
Install react redux
npm install react-router-dom@next

Paste in example lifted directly from docs

Run it
npm start